# Conflicting implementation for `matrix::Matrix<1, 1, _>`

Tags: rust

My Matrix Implementation

```
pub struct Matrix<const M: usize, const  N: usize, T: Num + Neg + Copy>(Box<[[T; N]; M]>);

impl<const M: usize, const  N: usize, T: Num + Neg + Copy> Index<(usize, usize)> for  Matrix<{M}, {N}, T> {
    type Output = T;

    fn index(&self, index: (usize, usize)) -> &Self::Output {
        &self.0[index.0][index.1]
    }
}
```

Definition of Column and Row Vectors from Matrix

```
type CVector<const N: usize, T> = Matrix<{1}, {N}, T>;
type RVector<const N: usize, T> = Matrix<{N}, {1}, T>;
impl<const N: usize, T: Num + Neg + Copy> Index<usize> for CVector<{N}, T> {
    type Output = T;

    fn index(&self, index: usize) -> &Self::Output {
        &self[(0,index)]
    }
}

impl<const N: usize, T: Num + Neg + Copy> Index<usize> for RVector<{N}, T> {
    type Output = T;

    fn index(&self, index: usize) -> &Self::Output {
        &self[(index,0)]
    }
}
```

Error

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `Index<usize>` for type `matrix::Matrix<1, 1, _>`
  --> src/vector.rs:38:1
   |
30 | impl<const N: usize, T: Num + Neg + Copy> Index<usize> for CVector<{N}, T> {
   | -------------------------------------------------------------------------- first implementation here
...
38 | impl<const N: usize, T: Num + Neg + Copy> Index<usize> for RVector<{N}, T> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ conflicting implementation for `matrix::Matrix<1, 1, _>`
```

I understand template specialization is not stable right now. Any tricks to get around this problem?

I tried Template Specialization.

Comment: Use a newtype around `Matrix`.

Comment: For more details on the newtype pattern, see [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/new_types.html).

Answer (score 1):

Even with specialization, these implementations would be impossible due to conflicts. Don't forget that a type alias is still identical to the underlying type for all purposes, so `impl<...> Index<usize> for CVector<N, T>` is exactly identical to `impl<...> Index<usize> for Matrix<{1}, N, T>`. You therefore have these two implementations:

```rust
impl<const N, T> Index<usize> for Matrix<{1}, N, T> { ... }
impl<const N, T> Index<usize> for Matrix<N, {1}, T> { ... }
```

In these case where `N == 1`, you have a conflict here: two implementations for `Index<usize> for Matrix<{1}, {1}, T>`, and neither is obviously more "specific" than the other for specialization purposes.

My advice would be to use newtypes for `RVector` and `CVector`:

```
struct RVector<const N, T>(Matrix<N, {1}, T>);
struct CVector<const N, T>(Matrix<{1}, N, T>);
```

You can then `impl Deref` on these to allow easy access to the underlying matrices, while still providing specialized vector-specific functionality like your `Index` implementation. With `repr(transparent)`, you can even add `unsafe` accessors that convert directly from `&Matrix<{1}, N, T>` to `&CVector<N, T>`, without additional copying.

Finally, I'd also recommend you use a pattern similar to the one I used in [`gridly`](https://docs.rs/gridly/latest/gridly/), my 2D grids library. There's a lot of functionality that is duplicated over row and column, so I use a [`Row`](https://docs.rs/gridly/latest/gridly/prelude/struct.Row.html) and [`Column`](https://docs.rs/gridly/latest/gridly/prelude/struct.Column.html) type instead of `usize` for indexing, and use a trait [`Component`](https://docs.rs/gridly/latest/gridly/location/trait.Component.html) to genericize over them. For instance, [`Grid::single_view`](https://docs.rs/gridly/latest/gridly/grid/trait.Grid.html#method.single_view) can get a view of either a single row or a single column (by calling `grid.single_view(Row(2))` or `grid.single_view(Column(4))`.